# how to pass multiple arguments and read in shell script

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to read multiple arugments are assign each to different variable in shell script

example:

```
.run.sh --argument1=value1 --argument2=value2 --argument3=value3
```

In my code I need to read this and assign as,

variable1=value1

variable2=value2

variable3=value3

I was trying to read in a loop but not sure how to read the value immediately after the "=" sign

```
for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
--argument1)
    variable1="..."
    shift
    ;;
esac
done
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as *java*?

Comment: could you update the question to show some examples? Your comment to [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61742901/1983854) suggests your parameters may change its order but need to be treated as the same when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Set `variable1=$2` then `shift 2`.

Although I would recommend instead using `getopts` for parameter parsing. A good reference would be [this blog post by Kevin Sookocheff](https://sookocheff.com/post/bash/parsing-bash-script-arguments-with-shopts/).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need an associative array.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=1
declare -A array

for f; do
  array["variable$((n++))"]=${f##*=}
done

echo "${array[variable1]}"
echo "${array[variable2]}"
echo "${array[variable3]}
```

Running that against your sample arguments.

```
./run.sh --argument1=value1 --argument2=value2 --argument3=value3
```

Output

```
value1
value2
value3
```

Although an option parser might be better for this kind of situation.

Comment: Do you think this works if I change the order, say
./run.sh  --argument2=value2 --argument1=value1 --argument3=value3

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, and I don't know if you really have numbers in the arguments and values. You can  remove the counter,  but you already voted for the other answer so use that?